# Ruby on Rails authentication that remembers previous page before login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

I'm looking for a solution that allows a user to:

1. Navigate to a page
2. Sign up or log in
3. Be re-directed to the first page

I have been using Devise for my application be seem to have hit a wall as Device always routes to the root_path after login. I have tried:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  session[:return_to] || root_path
end
```

But this does not work as the session[:return_to] does not seem to get getting set.

Can anyone shed any light on the best way to do this through Devise - or suggest an alternative Authentication solution that allows this type of action. Thanks

Comment: Hm, Devise was always doing this for me. I didn't write any custom code. Anyways, did you try `redirect_to :back`?

Comment: It works if the initial request is for a new or edit action but not if it is for a show action. I don't have a users controller so am not sure how to implement a redirect_to :back

Comment: I'm pretty positive it works (for me) for `show` actions too.

Comment: The problem was that I wasn't setting the session[:return_to] value - adding the before filter as mentioned below to the application controller fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you setting the session[:return_to] variable manually? Try adding this to your ApplicationController

```
before_filter :get_referrer, :except => [:create, :update, :destroy]

def get_referrer
  session[:return_to] = request.referrer
end
```

Alternatively, you can set your return_to session variable in each controller if you want to have more fine-grained control over which pages actually set the return_to session variable.

Comment: Thank you for this - it answered my question. It's such a simple step but one that I had missed.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to override `after_sign_in_path_for(resource)` in application_controller.rb as following:

```
private

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    stored_location_for(resource) || default
  end
```

Comment: Hi, yes this is how I thought it was done, however the stored_location_for(resource) object has no value - should this be set by Devise or do I need to assign it somewhere? I have also tried session[:"user_return_path"], session[:"return_path"] and all variations of symbols or strings but again no value is set for any.

Answer (score 0):

After login you could do simply this:

```
redirect_to request.referer.blank? ? root_path : :back
```

There is no need to store referer in session.